# сканирование директории на изменение в ней файлов

Tags: c++, c

как в с++ можно проверить в некоторой директории изменилось количество файлов? Хотелось бы вариант не привязанный к платформе

Comment: См. `<filesystem>`.

Comment: В linux можно воспользоваться [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Comment: В windows есть [Directory Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications?redirectedfrom=MSDN)